# Ajax MySQL POST responses with Object without data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using that code to send a POST request to add data to a mysql table.

```
var todoItem = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test",
    data: todoItem,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
      if(data.success){
        $('#todo-list').append(
          '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<span class="lead">' +
              data.todo +
            '</span>' +
            '<div class="pull-right">' +
              '<a href="/test/#/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>' +
              '<form style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/test/${data.id}">' +
                '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>' +
              '</form>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
          '</li>'
        );
      } else {
        $("#todo-list").append(
          '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<span class="lead">' +
              'Fail' +
            '</span>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
          '</li>'
        );
      }
    }
```

Then i want to use data from the response to append to my list.
But if(data.success) isnt passing. why is that?

Also my data in console.log looks like object Object and doesnt contain the inserted row data.

Do i need to send a get request now to retrieve the last data row?

Comment: Have you sent the expected response from server ?

Comment: When you are sending the response back are you converting is by using echo json_encode( data ); ? (assuming that you are using php on the server side)

Comment: sorry, didnt get your question. my data is sent to the DB and i can see it ith wokbench. but now i also want to display it immediately on the page. the data from the response seems to not have the row data itself only its insertedID.

Comment: I am using nodejs with express.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what do you mean by sending response back. I am trying to use the data variable from the success: response.